# Azure Pipeline sed file

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a problem with this pipeline and its work flow.
The idea I am trying to achieve, is to have a set of variables declared in my azure pipeline, and during the run time, I want to sed those variables name in a specific file before to push it to an azure blob storage.

So far this is how my pipeline looks like:

```
variables:
  - name: <email_1>
    value: <value1>

  - name: <email_2>
    value: <value2>

  - name: deployment_url
    value: <deployment>

  - name: storageaccount
    value: <my_storage_Account>
```

I set my 2 jobs for Seeding and Updating the file content with the variables

```
jobs:
- job: Seeding
  steps:
  - bash: |
     # Write your commands here
     email_2=${{ variables.email2 }}
     email_placeholder="{{value_to_change}}"
     url_placeholder="{{DEPLOYMENT_URL}}"
     echo "URL: "$DEPLOYMENT_URL
     echo "EMAIL:" ${{ variables.email2 }}

     sed -i "s|$email_placeholder|$email_2|g" ReportPhishingOutlookAddInWeb/Functions/FunctionFile.js

     sed -i "s|$url_placeholder|$DEPLOYMENT_URL|g" ReportPhishingOutlookAddIn.xml
    workingDirectory: Folder
```

What I am expecting to see, is that the value in my Function.js (which contain a line as "{{value_to_change}} get changed with the value of "email_2", same behaviour for the `deployment_url`

After this I have another job that pushes this folder into a azure blob storage. When I run the pipeline, it builds successfully and if I `echo` the `sed` I can she the variable replaced correctly, but when I head to my blob on azure and check the files, I see the original values and not the sed.

Any idea why is this happening or what am I doing wrong? please?

UPDATE:
In my pipeline I `cat` the files that I am trying to update with the `sed` and the output during the pipeline run, it shows that the value get correctly replaced, but during the upload, in my case is a azure upload-batch, it uploads the file original file I have in GitHub ignoring the sed from the previous step.

Comment: Can you share the configuration of your job which push folder to Azure blob storage? Please also share the debug log of this job.

Answer (score 1):

I just had exactly the same issue and ran the same check. My problem was that I wasn't accounting for the agent working directory (ex. /home/devops_agent_dev/azagent/_work/r2/a) so essentially, the file was getting changed, but then a different file was used later in the pipeline, which was why the change wasn't reflected.